# FTP Client with Email notifications?

Tags: snow-leopard, notifications, ftp

I'm looking for a FTP client that supports sending notification when transfers have completed. Does anyone know of one?

I'd like to trigger an email when files have finished uploading to a server.

Comment: How about the new Notification center of Growl notifications? Will that suffice?

Comment: If you're open to command-line hackery, this should be quite easy to do.

Comment: Does this need to happen for all transfers, or just to a specific destination? If the latter, a script/droplet to upload files and email on completion is doable, but otherwise a full client with this support would be needed (which I haven't seen yet).

Comment: I'd go with a script but the transfers arent always to the same destination and I'm not always the one starting the transfer... Might have to make a feature request with a developer

Answer (score 2):

You can also use any FTP client which supports Growl notifications (Transmit, Forklift, YummyFTP, whatnot).

In Growl's (v2) preferences, go to the **Displays** tab and configure the MailMe action. Then in the **Applications > Application** tab, select the MailMe action for all notifications or, alternatively, switch to **Applications > Notifications** and select the MailMe action just for the notification you want.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not tried it myself, [AbleFTP](http://hiteksoftware.com/ablef/ftp-client-macosx.htm) should do what you want. (Successful transfer should be task exit code 0.)

The same company also have a few other applications that claims to have email notification support, such as JaSFtp (link to Mac version broken on their homepage though) and [Automize](http://hiteksoftware.com/automation-software-Mac-OSX.htm), which seems like overkill if you only want FTP.

I also found [Captain FTP](http://www.captainftp.com/), which on the feature page claims to have email notification, but I can't find any information about that in the manual so I can't say under what circumstances it will send an email.

Answer (score 0):

[Captain FTP](http://www.captainftp.com/cftp/tour.html) has email notification and a free download... not to bad an interface design either.